# I want to include files in a html5boilerplate website

Tags: html, html5boilerplate

Is it possible to include often used files in a responsive html5boilerplate website?
php makes this easy possible like: 
So can I change the extension  .html in .php of the responsive boilerplate website? as php makes this possible.
I have the feeling that this is not a good idee.
Is there another way to include files in a html website? 
thank you for youre help , frank

Comment: Html5boilerplate is just a html template - using it does not mean you can't use php, or that the template must be used exactly as provided in the dowload/repository. If you want to use it with php - just make your layout file (whatever that is, if it's index.php then "yes") based on the index.html file of html5boilderplate.

Comment: thank you , i have understand youre answer. frank

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Boilerplate is a starting point, it include all of the necessary elements that you will need to begin. If you wanna use Php.  AD7six has right. You can create a index.php with the same code of index.html (the index.html provided by HTML5 Boilerplate) . And include the css, javascript, images, etc provided by HTML5 Boilerplate too.